# LRU cache with large-key. Referencing?

Tags: python, python-2.7, caching, memoization, lru

I'm having the following dilemma, implementing LRU algorithm.
For every entry I have to store (key, value, timestamp)
As you guessed the cache structure can be :

```
 cache[key] = [ value, tstamp ]
```

so far so good. The problem is that LRU algorithm requires that 
when I have to purge element (because the cache is full), I have to do
linear search on the time stamp to delete the least used item, which is slow.

On the other hand I can't build reverse hash tstamp => key, because the
key is 1KByte big and the additional memory usage will negate the use of the cache.

Any ideas to preserve the speed but not increase the memory usage ?

If I could have something as reference I could probably reference cache-key w/o allocating additional memory !

---

I can't use LRU lib, because the key is unhashable by default I have to transform it beforehand. I'm also using 2.7

Comment: Use https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a out-of-box LRU cache, refer to [functools.lru_cache](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache)

If you need to implement it yourself, use a linked list to keep track of the function call history, please refer to [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883177/how-does-lru-cache-from-functools-work/49883487#49883487) regards to how `functools.lru_cache` works internally.

Comment: this still doesn't resolve the large-key dilemma, right ?