# How to determine the required maxsize of lru_cache?

Tags: python, caching, memoization

If we are creating a recursive function like one that would return the Fibonacci sequence, and using the `lru_cache` .. What is the real governor of the `max size` parameter?

It is obvious that we only need the last two items when calculating each term.. but setting the `maxsize` to `2` and running the first `1000` calculation will take ages to finish.

I tried to use a cache dictionary that only contains two elements:

```
fib_cache = {0: 1, 1: 1}

def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        val = 1
    elif n == 2:
        val = 1
    elif n > 2:
        val = fib_cache[0] + fib_cache[1]

    fib_cache[0] = fib_cache[1]
    fib_cache[1] = val
    return val
```

Then, I run a similar function with `lru_cache`:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=3)
def fib1(n):
    if n == 1:
        val = 1
    elif n == 2:
        val = 1
    elif n > 2:
        val = fib1(n - 1) + fib1(n - 2)
    return val
```

I called the first 1000 calculation of each and the results are identical in terms of performance. However, I am not sure how to specify the `maxsize` parameter. I just found that, for this specific function, 2 would take ages and 3 works just fine. My guess is that it will be storing the result, here `fib1(n)`, together with the last two items that were used to calculate it, `fib1(n - 1) and fib1(n - 2)`, but why won't the result replace the oldest item immediately? Does `fib1(n)` take place in the cache memory before even being calculated?
Is there a way to view the `lru_cache` element? Maybe this would be helpful.

Comment: as a sidenote there is a way faster divide and conquer algorithm for fibonacci numbers https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-fibonacci-algorithms

Comment: to answer your question cache size and cache invalidation is more an art than exact science. Usually there are no known exact limits, trial and error uncovers the optimum parameters for each case

Comment: @Nikos M. Thanks, this is a cool method but it only works with Fibonacci sequence. I was hoping to find out about a more general method of specifying the required cache memory.. Say you have a more complicated function that returns a list of values each run rather than a single value.. As you said, trial and error might be a good way after all.. Thank you

Comment: On a side note: here you are already using O(n) stack space due to recursion, so just for the Fibonacci problem, there's little point in limiting the size of the LRU cache here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, **only caching 2 values is enough for Fibonacci computation**.

Your function doesn't work properly because **recursive calls are not set in the good order**. Add some print statements to your function and you will understand its behaviour.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def fib(n):
    print(f'calling fib({n})')
    if n == 1:
        val = 1
    elif n == 2:
        val = 1
    elif n > 2:
        val = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2)
    print(f'fib({n}) is being computed')
    return val

fib(5)

# calling fib(5)
# calling fib(4)
# calling fib(3)
# calling fib(2)
# fib(2) is being computed
# calling fib(1)
# fib(1) is being computed
# fib(3) is being computed
# calling fib(2)
# fib(2) is being computed
# fib(4) is being computed
# calling fib(3)
# calling fib(1)
# fib(1) is being computed
# fib(3) is being computed
# fib(5) is being computed
```

What's happening here is when you compute from `fib(4)`, it needs `fib(3)` and `fib(2)`. But `fib(3)` needed `fib(2)` **and then** `fib(1)`, so the 2 last calls were `fib(3)` and `fib(1`) so you need again to recompute `fib(2)`.

So you should switch `fib(n - 1)` and `fib(n - 2)` to make it work:

```
@lru_cache(maxsize=2)
def fib(n):
    if n == 1:
        val = 1
    elif n == 2:
        val = 1
    elif n > 2:
        val = fib(n - 2) + fib(n - 1)  
    return val
```