# treatment of `common` memoized python functions

Tags: python, caching, code-reuse

For a python application including the following modules:

**`commons.py`**

```
    @lru_cache(maxsize=2)
    def memoized_f(x):
        ...
```

**`pipeline_a.py`**

```
from commons import memoized_f

x = memoized_f(10)
y = memoized_f(11)
```

**`pipeline_b.py`**

```
from commons import memoized_f

x = memoized_f(20)
y = memoized_f(21)
```

1. does python store one `memoized_f` cache per `pipeline_*` module? so in the example above, there will be two caches, total for `memoized_f`? or
2. because the caching is defined for `memoized_f`, there is only cache stored here for `memoized_f` in the application containing all the modules above?

Comment: You could test this yourself by putting a `time.sleep` in the `memoized_f` and then check whether the function (= sleep) or the cache (= instant) gets queried.

Answer (score 0):

`@functools.lru_cache` doesn't do any magic. It is a function decorator, meaning it takes the annotated function (here: `memoized_f`) as input and defines a new function. Essentially it does `memoized_f = lru_cache(memoized_f, maxsize=2, ...)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49883466/2111778))

So your question boils down to whether a (function in a) module imported by two other modules shares state, to which the answer is **yes, there is a common cache.** This is because each module is only imported once.

See e.g. [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules)